# Pyjs not working with Tkinter

Tags: javascript, python, tkinter, pyjamas

I am trying to use pyjamas (http://pyjs.org/) to compile some python that I wrote into javascript. My python program works the way I want it to.  I installed via the installation guide on the website.

```
pyjsbuild -I --library_dir=/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk/ deployme.py
```

When I attempt to open the html that is generated I get (displayed in firefox):

deployme ImportError: No module named Tkinter.*, Tkinter.* in context null

I did a lot of searching and it appears that Tkinter and pyjs don't get along.
http://mail.python.org/pipermail/tutor/2012-May/089463.html

1 - I just wanted to see if anyone has had any success with using pyjs with Tkinter.  I have only provided 1 link of evidence that it might not and can't understand what is so special about Tkinter that I can't just tell pyjs where the additional libraries are and have it include them.

2 - Would it be easier for me to just learn some javascript and code my user interface (that I had made with Tkinter) in js?

3 - Is there another way I can accomplish running my python program on a website?

Comment: can you update with what you ended up doing? I have a tkinter gui but would like to add some javascript capabilities. Did you end up rewriting in javascript?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use Tkinter with pyjamas. pyjamas has it's own UI components. See http://pyjs.org/UIHierarchy.html

There is simply no way to display a tkinter application on a website.

Answer (score 0):

You may not use Tkinter in Pyjamas. Better use Brython. But it doesn't as well